# Download my application on the simulator. Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

After my Xcode simulator runned an old version of my application i clicked "erase all content and settings". Now my simulator doesn't show the application at all.
The app i made previews perfectly on the canvas in Xcode, but the app doesn't appear in the simulator.

I am running Xcode 11.5.
How do i get the updated app to run in the simulator?

Comment: in Xcode select the simulator you want to run on and click run, it will rebuild the app and copy it to the simulator and then attach to it for debuggging

Answer (score 0):

Just try to reopen Xcode and chose any simulator you want and wait until app will open

Answer (score 0):

Press Command + r, then Xcode will build the app and install it in your simulator. Might take 30 seconds or so, when it is done the app will launch automatically.